# Setting or Getting text on array items - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 divs on a page: `<div class="cell"></div>`.
I have those 'divs' stored in a variable named `$cell`...
So, if I console.log(`$cell`) I get an array with those 5 divs.
If I console.log(`$cell[2]`) I get the 3rd 'div'... All is well in the world.

My rookie question is: Why can I NOT **set** the text with `$cell[0].text('Title');`

If I give them titles I can NOT **get** the text either with `$cell[0].text();`

I get an error *" $cell[2].text is not a function "*

If it helps I am trying to SET the text in a for loop with data from an object

```
var $cell = $('.cell');
for(var i = 0; i<cell.length;i++) {
    $cell[i].text($table[i].name);
}
```

I tried using the .html() function as well... No Dice.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use the `text()` function from jQuery if you wrap each DOM element with `$()` like so: `$($cell[i]).text($table[i].name);`. By the way, if the `$cell` variable name is causing more confusion here, you could just call it `cells`.

Comment: `var $cells = $(".cell")` is a good naming convention to show it is a jQuery object

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to set DOM object content with a jQuery method.

Instead EITHER use

```
$cell[0].textContent=""; // [0] is the dom object
```

OR

```
$cell.eq(0).text(""); eq(0) is the jQuery object
```

BUT in your case try

```
$(".cell").each(function(i) {
  $(this).text($table[i].name); // $(this) is the current jQuery object
});
```

Using the DOM object:

```
$(".cell").each(function(i) {
  this.innerText = $table[i].name; // this is the current DOM node
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The object `$cell` is not a regular array, it is a jQuery object that happens to support indexing. But if you index it using `$cell[i]` then the result is a DOM object, instead of a jQuery-object, and the DOM object does not know what jQuery `.text()` is.

A possible fix is to apply `$()` again, this will work:

```
$($cell[i]).text("hello");
```

Another equally good way to get there is to *not* use indexing, but to use jQuery `.eq()` which does return a jQuery-object:

```
$cell.eq(i).text("hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `innerHTML`

```js
var $cell = $('.cell');
for(var i = 0; i<$cell.length;i++) {
    $cell[i].innerHTML = "foo " + i;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cell">1</div>
<div class="cell">2</div>
<div class="cell">3</div>
<div class="cell">4</div>
<div class="cell">5</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more complicated. You can convert JQuery object into an array  with $.makeArray(); and use $() to concert each element od the array into QUery for using the text() method for example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var cell = $(".cell");
//convert jquery object into array

var arr = $.makeArray(cell);

console.log($(arr[0]).text());


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cell">1</div>
<div class="cell">2</div>
<div class="cell">3</div>
<div class="cell">4</div>
<div class="cell">5</div>
```